# Return shortest path with Breadth-first search in prolog

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, shortest-path

I would like to find the shortest route from station A to station B in prolog in bidirectional graph(if A is connected to B than B is connected to A),the graph has no weights on branches. The question is posted like this

```
solve(Start,End,Path).
```

Start-starting station.
End-Destination station.
Path-List of all stations passed with the shortest route. The distance between any two directly connected stations in the graph is equal.
fact in base are like this:

```
fact("Staion1","metroline","Station2","metroline").
```

metro line is the number of line that connects the two staions directly. If 2nd and 4th argument are the same the stations are connected directly.

```
line("Abbesses","12","Pigalle","12").  
line("Abbesses","12","Lamarck Caulaincourt","12").  
line("Ale'sia","4","Mouton Duvernet","4").  
line("Ale'sia","4","Porte d'Orle'ans","4").  
line("Alexandre Dumas","2","Philippe Auguste","2").  
line("Alexandre Dumas","2","Avron","2").  
line("Alma Marcesu","9","Ie'na","9").
```

EDIT:
I tried to solve the problem and I figure out that it would work faster if use BFS.
here is the solution that I wrote:

```
solve(Start,End,Path):-solve1([Start],End,[Start],Path).   

solve1([P|O],End,Visited,[End|?]):-children(P,S),member(End,S),!.   
solve1([P|O],End,Visited,Path):-(not(member(P,Visited)),children(P,S),append(O,S,O1),solve1(O1,End,Visited,Path));  
(solve1(O,End,Visited,Path)).
```

?-should be the list with path to destination Node
The only problem is that i don't know how to return the path to the destination node.
Thank's ahead.

Comment: Tell us how you've started solving the problem and where you got stuck. It looks like you want others to solve this for you entirely...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dijkstra's algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It begs the question, whether a breadth first algorithm has any advantage over a depth first algorithm. You anyway detect cycles via the member/2 predicate, so there is no issue of completness.

Lets say we have this graph, without any cycles:

[image]

Which can be represented in Prolog as these facts:

```
% edge(-Vertex, -Vertex)
edge(a, b).         edge(a, c).
edge(a, d).         edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).         edge(c, e).
edge(d, e).
```

Then [tabling with aggregate functions](https://qiita.com/j4n_bur53/items/ffd387f7fe7cc604056a) does the job:

```
% path(+Vertex, +Vertex, -Integer)
:- table path(_,_,min).
path(X, X, 0).
path(X, Y, N) :-
   edge(X, Z), path(Z, Y, M), N is M+1.
```

Here are some example runs:

```
?- path(a, e, X).
X = 2
?- path(a, e, 3).
No
```

You can also modify the code, so that it detects cycles and/or returns paths. What is helpful for the later, is using custom aggregate functions.

Disclaimer: For practical purposes you wouldn't use something that boils down to Dijkstra's algorithm. You would rather use something from the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) family.